# SQL Server CE not supporting ExecuteSQLCommand with EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I've been developing a C# WPF project with VS2015 using SQL Server Express LocalDb with Entity Framework. I have built a custom seeder for the database, that reads test data from an Excel file, that simply combines the Excel data into a command string, and this is inserted using `context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand`.

Now, I was thinking of launching the project with SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0, but I find this command is not working anymore. Do I have to write my uploader again using `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` or am I missing something?

Also, from somewhere I have understood that with EF you can switch the SQL provider and the code would not need other changes. Am I in for more surprises down the road?

Example of the uploader command:

```
string cmd = "INSERT INTO Venues(Name, City, Telephone) Values ('X','Y','Z')"
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);
```

The error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = INSERT ]

This is not just a testing issue, as I would want to include this uploader in the production version, too, for quick inserting of master data (e.g. employee list).

**EDIT: Uploader code. If this can be done without resorting to raw SQL, that would be a good solution, too.**

This loops through Excel sheets (named after entities) and columns (first row has property name) and rows 2->n (data). This handles the upload of basically any amount of data within Excel limitations. The point is that the code has no knowledge of the entities (might have been possible to parameterize DataContext too). Code might not be optimal, as I'm just a beginner, but has worked for me, except not with SQL CE. Editing to suit CE is not a big issue, but I wanted to ask for possibly better ways.

```
public static class ExcelUploader
{
    static ArrayList data;
    static List<string> tableNames;

    public static string Upload(string filePath)
    {
        string result = "";
        data = new ArrayList();
        tableNames = new List<string>();
        ArrayList upLoadData = ReadFile(filePath);
        List<string> dataList = ArrayListToStringList(upLoadData);

        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            using (var trans = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var cmd in dataList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(cmd);
                        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    result = e.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show(result);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    private static ArrayList ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        List<string> commands = new List<string>();

        var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: true);
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        foreach (Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            var r = ws.UsedRange;
            var array = r.Value;
            data.Add(array);
            tableNames.Add(ws.Name);
        }
        wb.Close(SaveChanges: false);
        xlApp.Quit();

        return data;
    }

    private static List<string> ArrayListToStringList(ArrayList arrList)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        for(int tableAmount = 0;tableAmount<data.Count;tableAmount++)
        {
            result.Add(ArrayToSqlCommand(arrList[tableAmount] as Array, tableNames[tableAmount]));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static string ArrayToSqlCommand(Array arr, string tableName)
    {
        int propertyRow = 1;
        int firstDataRow = 2;
        string command = "";

        // loop rows                
        for (int rowIndex = firstDataRow; rowIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); rowIndex++)
        {
            command += "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(";

            //add column names
            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(1); colIndex++)
            {
                //get property name
                command += arr.GetValue(propertyRow, colIndex);

                //add comma if not last column, otherwise close bracket
                if (colIndex == arr.GetUpperBound(1))
                {
                    command += ") Values (";
                }
                else
                {
                    command += ", ";
                }
            }

            //add values
            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(1); colIndex++)
            {
                //get property value
                command += "'" + arr.GetValue(rowIndex, colIndex) + "'";

                //add comma if not last column, otherwise close bracket
                if (colIndex == arr.GetUpperBound(1))
                {
                    command += ");";
                }
                else
                {
                    command += ", ";
                }
            }
            command += "\n";
        }

        return command;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why using EF and raw SQL queries?

Comment: I constructed the Excel so, that worksheets are named after datasets and Excel columns' first row value is the database property with values on next rows. The uploader loops through the Excel file. I thought about building some sort of "general constructor", but I didn't manage to build a device that would construct an entity based on string inputs. For example, if I have entity 'Employee', is it possible to call its constructor by 'var entity = new GeneralConstructor("Employee")'? This would of course solve this problem neatly.

Comment: EF6 allows you to create entities on-the-fly with DbContext.Set method. But my wondering was why do you work with raw SQL when you can create entities and use EF in the way it's intended. :)

Comment: Because I could not implement the constructors to this Excel uploader, as I tried to explain. If you can tell me how to use it as intended for uploading data from Excel into dozens of tables without specific code for each entity, this info would be much appreciated. Currently, I manage this with about 50 lines of code, except it's not working for SQL CE.

Comment: Here's [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCjmyDHCJH6w0g393V) to test project. It contains also SQL used to create table. The database is already created and it's output is "Always copy". Also there's test Excel file with sample data. The entity filled by Excel's data is Employee. All other explanations are in comments.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort, but your solution states explicitly `var emp = new Employee` and `var set = db.Set<Employee>`, so this is just the entity-specific code I was wanting to avoid, as my uploader creates data for some 20 entities at once, and it should be able to handle any amount of entities, if need be. So, I am assuming raw sql is the only way to do this easily, and I should just create an SQL CE specific version of my uploader? Or then I'm missing something big time...

Comment: Could you connect with me in Skype? This way I'll get the picture more clearer than now)) My Skype: sekktor81

Comment: I have no Skype, but I included the uploader code, from which hopefully the idea becomes clear. But basically, you could answer my main question with just Yes/No, with perhaps comments on whether switching to CE will cause more problems.

Comment: I created [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/178293/ef-and-sql-server-ce). Please, join it so we could continue.

Comment: Apparently I need more rep to talk in chat :). Sorry. I'll install Skype on my other machine, where I have authorization. Just a moment, and thanks for you efforts.

Comment: OK!) Waiting for you in Skype...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to use raw SQL queries I'd offer.

### Initial data

#### 1) Excel table

```
+=======+=======+===========+
| Name  | City  | Telephone |
|===========================|
| Adam  | Addr1 | 111-11-11 |
|-------|-------|-----------|
| Peter | Addr2 | 222-22-22 |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

#### 2) SQL Server CE table

```
CREATE TABLE Venues
(
    Id        int identity primary key,
    [Name]    nvarchar(100) null,
    City      nvarchar(100) null,
    Telephone nvarchar(100) null
);
```

#### 3) Getting data from Excel

Here we're interested in getting array from Excel sheet. As soon as we get it, we can safely close Excel. The code assumes file "Employees.xlsx" to be next to executable file.

```
private object[,] GetExcelData()
{
    xlApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = false };
    var xlBook =
        xlApp.Workbooks.Open(System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                 Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                                 "Employees.xlsx"));
    var xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

    // For process termination
    var xlHwnd = new IntPtr(xlApp.Hwnd);
    var xlProc = Process.GetProcesses()
                 .Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle == xlHwnd)
                 .First();

    // Get Excel data: it's 2-D array with lower bounds as 1.
    object[,] arr = xlSheet.Range["A1"].CurrentRegion.Value;

    // Shutdown Excel
    xlBook.Close();
    xlApp.Quit();
    xlProc.Kill();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

    return arr;
}
```

Now you can use one of the ways to generate query.

#### Option 1. Use ExecuteSqlCommand

When using `ExecuteSqlCommand`, it's advisable to use parameterized queries to avoid errors. You can pass explicitly created `SqlCeParameter` or just pass a value.

```
private void UseExecuteSqlCommand()
{
    object[,] arr = GetExcelData();

    using (var db = new EmpContext())
    {

        db.Database.Initialize(true);

        int count = 0;
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Venues (Name, City, Telephone) " +
                     "VALUES (@name, @city, @phone);";

        // Start from 2-nd row since we need to skip header
        for (int r = 2; r <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++r)
        {
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                sql,
                new SqlCeParameter("@name", (string)arr[r, 1]),
                new SqlCeParameter("@city", (string)arr[r, 2]),
                new SqlCeParameter("@phone", (string)arr[r, 3])
            );

            ++count;
        }

        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show($"{count} records were saved.");
    }
}
```

#### Option 2. Use DbConnection

If you want your code to be more generic, you can create method which would accept `DbConnection`. This will allow to pass either `SqlConnection` or `SqlCeConnection`. But the code becomes more verbose because we can't use constructors since these classes are abstract.

```
private void UseDbConnection()
{
    object[,] arr = GetExcelData();

    using (var db = new EmpContext())
    {

        db.Database.Initialize(true);

        int count = 0;
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Venues (Name, City, Telephone) " +
                     "VALUES (@name, @city, @phone);";

        DbParameter param = null;

        DbConnection conn = db.Database.Connection;
        conn.Open();

        DbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Create parameters

        // Name
        param = command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@name";
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        // City
        param = command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@city";
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        // Telephone
        param = command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@phone";
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        // Start from 2-nd row since we need to skip header
        for (int r = 2; r <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++r)
        {
            command.Parameters["@name"].Value = (string)arr[r, 1];
            command.Parameters["@city"].Value = (string)arr[r, 2];
            command.Parameters["@phone"].Value = (string)arr[r, 3];
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ++count;
        }

        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show($"{count} records were saved.");
    }
}
```

You can also use ordinal positions for parameters which eliminates creating parameters names and makes code much shorter:

```
private void UseDbConnection()
{

    object[,] arr = GetExcelData();

    using (var db = new EmpContext())
    {

        db.Database.Initialize(true);

        int count = 0;
        // Take a note - use '?' as parameters
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Venues (Name, City, Telephone) " +
                     "VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

        DbConnection conn = db.Database.Connection;
        conn.Open();
        DbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Create parameters
        command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter());
        command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter());
        command.Parameters.Add(command.CreateParameter());

        for (int r = 2; r <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++r)
        {
            // Access parameters by position
            command.Parameters[0].Value = (string)arr[r, 1];
            command.Parameters[1].Value = (string)arr[r, 2];
            command.Parameters[2].Value = (string)arr[r, 3];
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ++count;
        }

        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show($"{count} records were saved.");
    }
}
```

**P.S.**
I didn't check whether the underlying connection is opened, but it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: I am overwhelmed by your effort! Thanks a lot, man. I accepted this as the answer and posted my updated code with further generalization. Alas, my upvotes don't seem to count...

Answer (score 0):

Based on JohnyL's excellent input, I was able to modify my code so that it works with either SQL Server Express and and SQL Server CE. I'll put my new code as an answer, as I had to parameterize it further, as I couldn't write the property names in the code either. But this was a simple step, once I got the idea from JohnyL. Not sure though, if the database writing operation should be wrapped inside a DbTransaction, but this worked for now.

```
public static class ExcelUploader
{
    static ArrayList data;
    static List<string> tableNames;
    static List<DbCommand> cmdList = new List<DbCommand>();
    static DbConnection conn;

    public static void Upload(string filePath)
    {
        data = new ArrayList();
        tableNames = new List<string>();
        //get Excel data to array list
        ArrayList upLoadData = ReadFile(filePath);

        using (var db = new DataContext())
        {
            conn = db.Database.Connection;

            //transform arraylist into a list of DbCommands
            ArrayListToCommandList(upLoadData);

            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                foreach (var cmd in cmdList)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var result = e.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
        }

    }

    //opens Excel file and reads worksheets to arraylist
    private static ArrayList ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        List<string> commands = new List<string>();

        var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: true);
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        foreach (Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
        {
            var r = ws.UsedRange;
            var array = r.Value;
            data.Add(array);
            tableNames.Add(ws.Name);
        }
        wb.Close(SaveChanges: false);
        xlApp.Quit();

        return data;
    }

    //transforms arraylist to a list of DbCommands
    private static void ArrayListToCommandList(ArrayList arrList)
    {
        List<DbCommand> result = new List<DbCommand>();

        for (int tableAmount = 0; tableAmount < data.Count; tableAmount++)
        {

            ArrayToSqlCommands(arrList[tableAmount] as Array, tableNames[tableAmount]);
        }

    }

    private static void ArrayToSqlCommands(Array arr, string tableName)
    {
        //Excel row which holds property names
        int propertyRow = 1;
        //First Excel row with values
        int firstDataRow = 2;
        string sql = "";

        DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        sql += "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(";

        //add column names to command text
        for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(1); colIndex++)
        {
            //get property name
            sql += arr.GetValue(propertyRow, colIndex);

            //add comma if not last column, otherwise close bracket
            if (colIndex == arr.GetUpperBound(1))
            {
                sql += ") Values (";
            }
            else
            {
                sql += ", ";
            }
        }

        //add value parameter names to command text
        for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(1); colIndex++)
        {
            //get property name
            sql += "@" + arr.GetValue(propertyRow, colIndex);

            //add comma if not last column, otherwise close bracket
            if (colIndex == arr.GetUpperBound(1))
            {
                sql += ");";
            }
            else
            {
                sql += ", ";
            }
        }

        //add data elements as command parameter values
        for (int rowIndex = firstDataRow; rowIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); rowIndex++)
        {
            //initialize command
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= arr.GetUpperBound(1); colIndex++)
            {
                //set parameter values
                DbParameter param = null;
                param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@" + (string)arr.GetValue(propertyRow, colIndex);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.Parameters[param.ParameterName].Value = arr.GetValue(rowIndex, colIndex);
            }
            //add command to command list
            cmdList.Add(cmd);

        }

    }
}
```